# C# deserialize multiple JSON collections into a single List<T>

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I fetch a collection of collections of the same object from a web api.
I would then like to deserialize the JSON into a single List

The JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "Liverpool": [
    {
      "playerId": "LIV01",
      "name": "Adam Llana",
      "position": "Midfielder"
    },
    {
      "playerId": "LIV02",
      "name": "Daniel Sturridge",
      "position": "Forward"
    }
  ],
  "ManchesterUnited": [
    {
      "playerId": "MNU01",
      "name": "Daley Blind",
      "position": "Defender"
    },
    {
      "playerId": "MNU02",
      "name": "Romelu Lukaku",
      "position": "Forward"
    }
  ],
  "Arsenal": [
    {
      "playerId": "ARS01",
      "name": "Petr Cech",
      "position": "Goalkeeper"
    },
    {
      "playerId": "ARS02",
      "name": "Santi Cazorla",
      "position": "Midfielder"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I could like to be able to do is the following as I am not interested in the collection names:

```
public class Player
{
    public string playerId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
}

List<Player> cards = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(jsonContent);
```

This does not work and produces an error.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Player]' because the type
>   requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix
>   this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or
>   change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
>   not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
>   or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

Is there any way to accomplish this using Newtonsoft.Json?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the variable team names you need to deserialize into `Dictionary<string, List<Player>>`. From there use `SelectMany` on the values of the dictionary to get the players

```
public class Player
{
    public string playerId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
}

var teams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Player>>>(jsonContent);
List<Player> players = teams.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to deserialize that object as a dictionary:

```
var teams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Player>>>(jsonContent);
```

The original object isn't an array so it doesn't make sense to deserialize it as an array or a `List<T>`

Later, if you want only the player list and don't care about the club names, then just use LINQ's `SelectMany` to flatten the dictionary:

```
var allPlayers = teams.SelectMany(entry => entry.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply try to create an object for players right now it won't work as the team names are unique. Your class to deserialize should look like this:

```
public class Teams
{
    public Liverpool[] Liverpool { get; set; }
    public Manchesterunited[] ManchesterUnited { get; set; }
    public Arsenal[] Arsenal { get; set; }
}

public class Liverpool
{
    public string playerId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
}

public class Manchesterunited
{
    public string playerId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
}

public class Arsenal
{
    public string playerId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can straight away deserialize the data to this object.

```
Teams teams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Teams>(jsonContent);
```

Their is an option know as **Paste Special** inside the **Edit** option in the top **File Menu**, this option lets you create classes that mimics the properties of a **json or xml**.

Comment: What if OP has 1000 teams to deserialize? What if their names are unknown beforehand? What if a new property is added to the `Player` in the future?

Comment: Ya that is an issue with this implementation.Thanks for highlighting the issue.